# C# winforms RDLC report direct print to printer

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an app with VS2017 C# WinForms, created a report for a table inside with RDLC reportviewer, the report is working well, I want to print this report directly and send it to the printer without popping up print preview dialog.

Please be informed that I googled this issue and searched this site as well and I couldn't find a solution.

Tried to use the MSDN topic (Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview) but still no luck.

Here is my button which runs several queries including opening a form (voucher) containing an rdlc reportviewer which loads data to show up in the report:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.switch_8);
            player.Play();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text == "0")
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Please select an item!");


            }
            else
            {
                MOVE_TO_SOLD();
                UPDATE_RECEIPT();
                LOAD_DATA();


                CLEAR_TEMP();
                CHECK_FOR_REC_ID();
                GET_NEW_REC_ID();
                LOAD_DATA();
                txtdiscount.Text = "0";
                textBox5.Text = "0";
                recowner.Text = recnum.Text;
                voucher vr = new voucher();
                vr.ShowDialog();

            }


        }
```

Thank You!

Comment: Instead of using `.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();`, You can use `.Print();` directly.

Comment: Could you please make it more clear to me ? Thanks !

Comment: To let me be more helpful, please add some codes that we can detect what you have to do.

Comment: I did edit the question, please see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx) will be very helpful for your problem. Please check it out, and if this answer was helpful, mark it as an answer.